# Regex with optional number and leading char ? (lua match)

Tags: lua, numbers, lua-patterns

I'm a beginner with regex and I'd like (for string.match() under lua) a regex that would recognize a positive or negative number prefixed by a special character (example : "!").
Example :

```
"!1" -> "1"
"!-2"  ->  "-2"
"!+3"  ->  "+3"
"!"  ->  ""
```

I tried

```
!(^[-+]?%d+)
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Just remove `^` and `!([-+]?%d+)` will work.

Comment: try `s:gmatch(".-!([-+]?%d+).-")` if `s` is a big string

Comment: No, `!([-+]?%d+)` is totally enough.

Comment: your solutions does not match "!" alone (last case of my example in the main post). I don't know if it's calssical, but in lua string.match can return NIL if nothing is found, but can return "" if something is found but nothing in it ;-)

Comment: This is not possible, in Lua patterns, there is no optional group support.

Comment: OK, so no possibility in one match to solve my example above (with the "!" alone) ? Then I'll do a separate find("!") after a failed match.

Comment: It will just find any `!`, but if you use an `if` condition, thus sorting out those that match `!([-+]?%d+)`, then it should work.

Comment: @MikeV. Why the surrounding `.-`? That's superfluous and appears to me as if it would likely slow down `gmatch`. Just `s:gmatch"!([-+]?%d+)"` is probably the most efficient it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern only contains minor mistakes:

- The start-of-string anchor `^` is misplaced (and thus treated as a character); the pattern anchor for end-of-string `$` is missing (thus the pattern only matching part of the string would be allowed).
- You're not allowing an empty number: `%d+` requires at least one digit.

Fixing all of these, you get `^!([-+]?%d*)$`. Explanation:

- `^` and `$` anchors: Match the full string, from start to end.
- `!`: Match the prefix.
- `(`: Start capture.
- `[-+]?`: Match an optional sign.
- `%d*`: Match zero or more digits.
- `)`: End capture.

Note that this pattern will also accept `!+` or `!-`.

Comment: Thanks. 
- I forgot to say that I'm searching this pattern anywhere in a big string. So maybe I do not need any ^ or $ ?
- your solution is almost perfect, but it recognizes "!-" or "!+" which should not be allowed... Is there a way to write something like (expr1) or (expr2) ? So it could be "!([-+]?%d+)" OR "!()". And the second would return an empty string...

Comment: You **must** remove the anchors `^` and `$` if you're searching in a string, yes.
Unfortunately Lua patterns have no "or" (alternation/choice, usually denoted by the pipe `|`) operator. You'll have to add additional Lua code to check for these patterns, such as calling `string.match` two times with two different patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a `match("!([-+]?%d+)")` and if there is no result, I do a `find("!")` to handle the lonely `"!"` case.

Too bad that Lua does not have `|` for `or`...